# Installing sqlite for g++ in windows console

Tags: c++, c, windows, sqlite, gcc

I'm trying to write a program that reads data from a .sqlite file. Firstly I used Dev C++ but I couldn't load sqlite3 files into Dev C++. But I want to do that in my windows command prompt with my g++ compiler.
Now I'm trying this code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "sqlite3.c"
int main(){
   sqlite3 *db;
   printf("%d",sqlite3_open("cookies.sqlite",&db));
}
```

I compiled it with this command "gcc sqltest.c -o test.exe"
It gives me an error message telling me that its the wrong windows version. It tells me that I need to check if I need a 32-bit or 64-bit version of the program. My windows is 32 bit. As far as I remember I downloaded the gcc for 32 bit windows. What do I need to solve this?

Comment: Show the exact error message.

Comment: It seems that I have solved the problem